# Which component use for displaying a paragraph of text in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to show a paragraph of text. I have tried `UILabel` but this makes the text vertically aligned: it does not start from top. If I use `UITextView` and  disable the properties selectable and editable it behaves like `UILabel`. Which component should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use UILabel to TextView with [NSAttributtedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/).

Also you can also set your ULLabel or textview text attribute from storyboard .
[image]
[image]

Comment: but i can't set it position from top

Comment: Look in details NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName attribute of NSAttributedString

Comment: I am going to use UITextView which will reduce the efforts for writing the code for position the text of uilabel